# Having trouble creating choropleth of the U.S. using ggplot2 in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I'm trying to create a choropleth of the percentages of individuals fully vaccinated against COVID-19 in the United States. I was able to throw some code together using ggplot, but when I run it, it only shows Alaska, Hawaii, and a couple of fragments of other states. The legend is also incorrect.

```
# Read in vaccine dataset through the wizard, named the dataframe "USVax" 

# Get map data of the world
mapdata <- map_data("world")

# Rename "state" column to "subregion" so that we can use left_join
USVax <- rename(USVax, subregion = state)

# Join dataframes
mapdata <- left_join(mapdata, USVax, by = "subregion")

# Get rid of extra rows that are not in the U.S.
mapdata1 <- mapdata %>% filter(!is.na(mapdata$People_Fully_Vaccinated))

# Make plot
map1 <- ggplot(mapdata1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = People_Fully_Vaccinated), color = "black")
```

The following choropleth is produced:

[choropleth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxuq1.png)

Comment: As you only want a map of the US have you considered using the `usmap` package?

Comment: Have you considered using one of the choroplethr packages? https://arilamstein.com/packages/